# How to save java.util.logging output in docker volume

Tags: java, docker, dockerfile, java.util.logging

i have a java application. I export my project as a .war file, build a docker container and run it.

The structure is the following. For the logging i use the library from java.

```
import java.util.logging.Logger;
```

In my application i define my variable:

```
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(BusController.class.getName());
```

And for the output i use for example:

```
logger.warning("User "+XYZ+" not found!");
```

When i start my dockerfile, i mount an extra volume for the logs.

```
REGISTRY=xxxxx.net
VERSION=latest
IMAGE=busMicroservice
SERVICE=busmicroservice
LOCAL_DATA_PATH=/opt/docker-busmicroservice/data

docker run -p xxxx:xxxxx -d -v $LOCAL_DATA_PATH:/logs --name $SERVICE --hostname $SERVICE $REGISTRY/$IMAGE:$VERSION
```

After the docker container has started successfully , i can check my volume with

```
docker inspect busmicroservice
```

and can see, that my volume is included.
But what do i have to do now, that the logs will be saved in my folder "/logs"? What do i have to implement in my java application?

Thank you in advance!

---------   EDIT    ----------

I have a second thread now for an additional question:
[How to save logfiles into a docker volume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47814379/how-to-save-logfiles-into-a-docker-volume)

Comment: Maybe read [a tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-logging/index.html)? Short story - create a logging configuration file and point your application at it.

Comment: yes, i know how to save my logging into a .txt file. But how to point to $LOCAL_DATA_PATH:/logs? Because otherwise i save it locally on a windows machine

Comment: Write the logs to `/logs`. I don't really understand your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use log4j file appender.
Edit log4j.properties

```
log4j.appender.default.file=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.default.file.append=true
log4j.appender.default.file.file=/log/logfile.log
log4j.appender.default.file.threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.default.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.default.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%-5p %c: %m%n
```

When application starts it will write log in /log/logfile.log file

For complete sample with java application can refer below.
https://dzone.com/tutorials/java/log4j/log4j-file-appender-example-1.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried your solution, and partially it worked, but now i have restructured my code and because of this i have a new problem.