# How to save logfiles into a docker volume

Tags: java, docker, dockerfile, java.util.logging

i have a java application. I export my project as a .war file, build a docker container and run it.

In my application i define my variable:

```
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(BusController.class.getName());
```

And for the output i use for example:

```
logger.warning("User "+XYZ+" not found!");
```

Then i have created a logback.xml, that the logs will be saved at my HDD with a timestemp. I found the solution for this also here.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

<include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>

<logger name="org.springframework.web" level="INFO"/>

<timestamp key="Timestamp" timeReference="contextBirth" datePattern="yyyy-MM-dd'_'HH-mm-ss"/>

<!-- Send debug messages to System.out -->
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <!-- By default, encoders are assigned the type ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder -->
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS}  - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>/opt/docker-busapi/data/logs/busicroservice-${myTimestamp}.log</file>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss} - %msg%n</Pattern>
    </encoder>

    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
        <FileNamePattern>busmicroservice.%i{yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss.SSS}}.log</FileNamePattern>
    </rollingPolicy>

    <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
        <MaxFileSize>30MB</MaxFileSize>
    </triggeringPolicy>
</appender>

<logger name="mypackage" level="INFO" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</logger>
```

That works, all my logs will be saved in my windows environment under "/opt/docker-busapi/data/logs" (i created the folder structure)

I also could mount my extra volume now via the -v parameter in my dockerfile:

```
REGISTRY=xxxxx.net
VERSION=latest
IMAGE=busMicroservice
SERVICE=busmicroservice
LOCAL_DATA_PATH=/opt/docker-busapi/data

docker run -p xxxx:xxxxx -d -v $LOCAL_DATA_PATH:/logs --name $SERVICE --hostname $SERVICE $REGISTRY/$IMAGE:$VERSION
```

Because if i check my docker container, the volume is mounted. 
Via "docker inspect busmicroservice" i get:

```
    "Mounts": [
    {
        "Type": "bind",
        "Source": "/opt/docker-busapi/data",
        "Destination": "/logs",
        "Mode": "",
        "RW": true,
        "Propagation": "rprivate"
    }
```

But my logs won't be saved in my logs folder. 
I guess there is still something wrong with the path. Which Path do i have to put in my "docker run" command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're not consistent on your file path names, in some places you have this defined:

```
/opt/docker-busapi/data/logs/
```

While in others, you have:

```
/opt/docker-busmicroservice/data
```

And then in the Docker container, you're saying that this should be used in the container:

```
/logs
```

If you want all your files to go to the **host directory** of `/opt/docker-busapi/data/logs/` then, first be sure that directory exists and you have the correct permissions set on it, and then ensure that your **application** uses `/logs` as it's directory to save in.

Then when you run:

```
docker run -p xxxx:xxxxx -d -v /opt/docker-busapi/data/logs:/logs --name my_service --hostname my_hostname image:version
```

Then you should be good to go.